# Need Help in ajax debugging

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myButton').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "testajax.aspx/GetHello",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#myLabel').text(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Click me" />
            <%--<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click me" />--%>
            <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public partial class DataUpdate__testa : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

is set in the web.config

Looking for a long time still don't know what is wrong..
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please tell us what is not working. Also spamming the word details, does not help

Comment: Can't run ajax properly, or do you mean you can run it properly?

Comment: Does anyone know this difficult questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code behind page looks REALLY but REALLY messed up.

Start from scratch. Add a new blank page, say called testajax.aspx.

So, the code inside of the page will be this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    static public string GetHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

DO NOT mess around with anything else in that page. In fact, when you type in the above [WebMethod], vs should automatic add to the using's this:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

But, DOUBLE check that the above "using" exists on this test page.

Now, of course I don't mess with the rest of the code or how the page is created. (and YOU should not have to either!!!!).

So, while I did not type in the rest of the page, a full code behind code listing would be this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CSharpWebApp
{
    public partial class testajax : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        static public string GetHello()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }

    }
```

But, of course YOU only typed in the ONE simple web method on that page of our simple routine GetHello.

NOTE VERY careful:

Since this is a not a separate custom "asmx" web service page, then ANY and ALL methods in that page MUST be marked as static. (it is your free choice to add methods to a asmx page, or as I often do, shove them into a existing web page, but for EXISTING aspx pages, you MUST as noted mark the function as static.

Ok, and now your js code. You have a whole bunch of extra trailing ):: etc. The editor should help you, but to be fair, js code can be hard, since it not compiled nor resolved during the build process.

However, our markup can thus look like this:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      function myjavatest() {

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "testajax.aspx/GetHello",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: {},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  $('#myLabel').text(data.d);
              },
              error: function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
              }
          });
      }

  </script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click me"
                OnClientClick="myjavatest();return false" />

            <br />
             <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text=""  ClientIDMode="Static"/>


        </div>
    </form>
```

So, above is all you need.

A few things:

As noted, WHEN you going to add web methods to a existing page, then make sure it marked as static.

Next up:

To reference controls on a page with jQuery, then make the label, or text box, or whatever with clientid="Static". (since the asp.net processor will mess with id names, this setting prevents that).

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I have successfully run it. 
I would like to ask what is the difference between System.Web.UI.Page and System.Web.Services.WebService? And where do I need to use System.Web.Services.WebService?
Becuase I saw this when I was building ASMX.

Comment: WebService means quite much what it means. You need that if you add/use/have System.WebServices (such as webmethods). As for System.Web.UI? That quite much defaulted for every page, and if you use things like HtmlTextWriter or other code that creates web controls or uses them, then you quite much need the System.Web.UI. So "UI" means stuff for web controls in code behind. So, yes, both a regular page, and a .asmx page will of course have System.WebServices if you have/want webmethods  (and the editor will put in those using automatic for a asmx page, but not for a aspx.page).

Comment: I encountered a problem, tried the same ajax code. One project works fine, but one project does not work. Am I ignoring some ajax settings? (Both sides have added jquery and web.config protocols settings)

Comment: Same ajax code. A project can run normally, but one project found error in F12 network about
{Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"Message: "Authentication failed."StackTrace: null
Do you know the solution?

Comment: I have no more idea then what you ate yesterday for lunch, or the color of the shirt you are wearing. If you have another question, then post the code and a re-producible error. With such code posted, then "many" 1,000's of people on SO can look at the code and see why it does not work. So, start a new question, post the page markup, the code behind, and then we can start some kind of suggesting process.

Comment: Just for Note(Problem solved): 
Inside ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs 
change: settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent; 
To 
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;